# MySQL display fetch based on best ratio

Tags: mysql

September 21         John                    Jill           Jake

PCs sold                    50                30            30
Keyboards sold           2                  7            11
Speakers sold           18                  8            14
Mice sold                     5                15              5
Ratio*                       50%            100%        100%

September 22         John                    Jill           Jake

PCs sold                    20                10            60
Keyboards sold           2                  7              1
Speakers sold           18                  8            14
Mice sold                     5                15              5
Ratio*                       125%            300%        50%

*of extras per PC sold (Sum(Keyboards, Speakers, Mice) / PC)

The best that I came up with which doesn't work because it sums the entire month as opposed to just the highest ratio day is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT User, 
DATE(`Created`) as DATE, 
sum(PCs) as PCsTotal,
sum(Keyboards) as KeyboardsTotal, 
sum(Speakers) as SpeakersTotal, 
sum(Mices) as MiceTotal, 
sum(KeyboardTotal + SpeakersTotal + MiceTotal) as Extras,
(Extras / PCsTotal) as Ratio
From my_db
where `Created` >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and `Created` <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 0 day
GROUP BY  Ratio
HAVING (sum(KeyboardsTotal)>5) and (sum(MiceTotal)>5)
LIMIT 1
```

Requested result:
Highest to lowest ratio displayed as a fetch in a HTML table, unique to each User:

User                    PCs            Keyboards          Speakers          Mice               Ratio

Jill                         10                       7                        8                 15                  300%    
Jake                      30                     11                      14                   5                  100%    
John                       -                        -                        -                    -                       -    
(John didn't meet the HAVING criteria)

Comment: I can't understand the question. what is your original table structure from which you want to fetch the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.User, a.`DATE`, a.PCsTotal, a.KeyboardsTotal, a.SpeakersTotal, 
  a.MiceTotal, a.Extras, a.Ratio
FROM (
  SELECT User, 
    DATE(`Created`) as `DATE`, 
    SUM(PCs) as PCsTotal,
    SUM(Keyboards) as KeyboardsTotal, 
    SUM(Speakers) as SpeakersTotal, 
    SUM(Mices) as MiceTotal, 
    SUM(KeyboardTotal + SpeakersTotal + MiceTotal) as Extras,
    (SUM(KeyboardTotal + SpeakersTotal + MiceTotal) / SUM(PCs)) as Ratio
  FROM my_db
  WHERE `Created` >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND `Created` <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 0 day
  GROUP BY User, `DATE`
  HAVING (sum(KeyboardsTotal)>5) and (sum(MiceTotal)>5)
) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT User, MAX(Ratio) as max_day_ratio
  FROM (
    SELECT User,
      DATE(`Created`) as `DATE`, 
      (SUM(KeyboardTotal + SpeakersTotal + MiceTotal) / SUM(PCs)) as Ratio
    FROM my_db
    WHERE `Created` >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      AND `Created` <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 0 day
    GROUP BY User, `DATE`
    HAVING (sum(KeyboardsTotal)>5) and (sum(MiceTotal)>5)
  ) c
  GROUP BY User
) b ON b.User = a.User
WHERE a.Ratio = b.max_day_ratio
```

Comment: Amazing work. Thank you. I would upvote but I don't have the required reputation.